# List filter within the outer range - KOTLIN

Tags: list, filter, kotlin

I have just started learning kotlin, and I stumbled upon this small issue. I have a list of Objects, and am filtering the list within a specified range. Am able to get the objects with in the range, but when I changed the range to outer bound, am getting an empty array,

So to keep the question simple, lets say am having a list of integers like

```
   original list [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

and am having a dropper function, which filters out the elements

> working condition

```
 fun dropper(args: ArrayList<Int>): List<Int> {
     return args.filter { it in 2..6 }  // it >= 2 && it <= 6
 }
```

output is received as

```
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

but when I change the range to

```
fun dropper(args: ArrayList<Int>): List<Int> {
    return args.filter { it in 4..2 }  // it <= 2 && it >= 4
    // it in 4..2 , was suggested by the IDE
}
```

getting output as an empty list.

Am pretty much sure that the list value is not clearing, because after this function is called am passing the list to an other operation which gives the intended result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than these answers, I also found out that `!` operation works as well

```
fun dropper(args: ArrayList<Int>): List<Int> {
    return args.filter { it !in 2..4 }  // it <= 2 && it >= 4
}
```

Comment: This just returns the original list (well, a copy of it), since no value can be in the `4..2` range, and therefore this filter condition is always true. (Or in other words `it !in 4..2` is true for any `it` value, because nothing is in `4..2`). Also, the operarator you're making use of here is actually [`!in`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#in).

Answer (score 3):

`4..2` is basically an empty range, because it translates to `it >= 4 && it <= 2`. To create a range that's decrementing, you have to use `downTo`:

```
args.filter { it in 4 downTo 2 }
```

`reversed` can also be an alternative in some cases:

```
args.filter { it in (2..4).reversed() }
```

This specific problem is also the first example in Dan Lew's recent [blog post](http://blog.danlew.net/2017/06/05/musings-on-kotlin-ranges/) that covers ranges nicely.

Comment: Gold!! Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

Use `downTo`. read [Ranges](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html) for detailed description.

Range (`x..y`), here x is starting index and y is last and it goes incremental way. So `1..10` range have 10 elements but `10..1` looks from 10 on-wards so it is an empty range. You need to use `downTo` operator.

Change your code like following:

```
fun dropper(args: ArrayList<Int>): List<Int> {
    return args.filter { it in 4 downTo 2 }  // it <= 2 && it >= 4
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello you need to use operator `downTo`

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   var list = arrayListOf<Int>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
   println(dropper(list)) // [2, 3, 4]
}

fun dropper(args: ArrayList<Int>): List<Int> {
   return args.filter { it in  4 downTo 2 }  // [2, 3, 4]
}
```

Here is fully described how to use ranges. - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html#ranges

Comment: Think i need to dig deeper on the kotlinDocs, Thanks BTW :)